# Validate url in PHP & Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, url-validation

I want to validate following kind of url's in jquery and in PHP at both client and server side validation.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_China (without www)
- www.wikipedia.org/ (without http, later when we validate this at PHP then we'll check if http:// is not there then we'll add it)

I have created regex to validate url in jquery

```
^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)
```

But its not validating URL `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_China` and giving error.

Please help

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this for php

```
preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $_POST['link'])
```

jquery

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("complete_url", function(val, elem) {
    // if no url, don't do anything
    if (val.length == 0) { return true; }

    // if user has not entered http:// https:// or ftp:// assume they mean http://
    if(!/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(val)) {
        val = 'http://'+val; // set both the value
        $(elem).val(val); // also update the form element
    }

    return /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(val);
});
```

addd this to form

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        url: "complete_url"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/452) solution.

Here is the snippet of code from that page:

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```

You can use the same regex in PHP for the server side validation.

Answer (score 1):

[This JQUery Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) will help you with validation and its really easy to use Plus you will have LIVE server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the requirement for the hostname to start with `www.` if you want to allow URLs that don't.

Answer (score 0):

The Php Code is:

```
if(preg_match('/((((?:http|https|ftp):\/\/)|(www\.))(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?[^\s\"\']+)/i',$str))
{
    echo "This is valid url.";
}
```