# Javascript URL validation

Tags: javascript, url-validation

I wrote a javascript validation script to validate if the URL contains **'+'** or **whitespaces**.

```
$.validator.addMethod("reportFileURL",
                    function(value,element){
                        if(((value.search(/[+]+/)) == -1) 
                                  && ((value.search(/[ ]+/))) == -1){
                           return true;
                        }
                     },"Invalid filename");
```

Can i write the script more precise than this.

Comment: You can find regex solution on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397157/validate-url-in-php-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (value.search(/[\s+]/) == -1) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanx Michael it works...:)    By the way can you suggest me a book or website to use regex for javascript form validation.

Comment: @SangramAnand glad it was helpful :) I use http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ to test my regular expressions of JS & PHP

Comment: If you want to target all whitespace (and not just the space character), you should change the regex to `/[\s+]/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return value.search(/[ +]/) == -1;
```